# Load JSON file from the file name passed in the parameter

Tags: angularjs, json

I want to read data from json file. I passed the file name as parameter and try to load data from  `data/{{filename}}.json` 
But it cannot found the file and shows this error message

```
data/%7B%7Bfilename%7D%7D.json 404 (Not Found)
```

Here is my function

```
    $scope.getSelectedCategoryData=function(fileName){
        $http.get('data/{{filename}}.json')
            .success(function (data) {
                $scope.selectedCategoryData = data.GetAllData;
            })
            .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            })
    }
```

And my question is how can I load the file from the value passed in parameter. Is there any way like this?

```
<img ng-src="img/{{image}}.png"/>
```

Comment: build the string using simple concatenation  `$http.get('data/'+fileName+'.json')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mustache notation is meant to use in html and not in Javascript. You have to follow the standard Javascript string concatenation. The below example will work for you.

```
$scope.getSelectedCategoryData=function(fileName){
        var filePath= 'data/' + fileName +'.json';
        $http.get(filePath)
            .success(function (data) {
                $scope.selectedCategoryData = data.GetAllData;
                $scope.image=data.GetAllData.image //image path
            })
            .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            })
    }
```

Then you can use:

```
<img ng-src="img/{{image}}.png"/>
```